# Add Wordpress to Website

Tags: html, wordpress, content-management-system

I'm starting to develop a new **HTML** website for traveling using **Dreamweaver**. I'm also plans to **integrate Wordpress** to manage content of the website.

My questions are,

1. Where can i found tutorials to integrate **Wordpress** to my **HTML** website on localhost (*for testing purposes*)?
2. Can i add new web pages using wordpress?
3. If i want to migrate from **HTML** to **ASP.NET** etc., will it be possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Wordpress uses HTML. All the markup WordPress generates is HTML.
2. Yes. It is easy as selecting *new page*.
3. They are not the same thing. Using .net will mean you will use HTML for the markup. .net is just a framework you use.

If you want to develop websites and have a greater understanding of the markup and code, use the code view of Dreamweaver.

Comment: Can you explain more on questions 1 & 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

To run WordPress locally, you'll need to install a local server environment (e.g. XAMPP, MAMP, WAMP), and from there you can pretty much install just like you would on a normal server. Here's a [good guide to installing WordPress locally](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/installing-wordpress-locally/).